# python oracle SQL query conversion

Tags: python, oracle

I'm trying to get a certain value from an oracle database and print a string with the value of the oracle database query.

```
con=cx_Oracle.connect('username/pword')
cur=con.cursor()
fList=()
obj=cur.execute('''select sequence from genes where key=54321''')
cur.close()
con.close()
print str(obj)
```

I get this output:

```
<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to user hendrik@local>>
```

But I'd like to get the value of sequence for this unique key/row.

Comment: `obj` is a python generator object. You can loop through it (`for item in obj:`) to retrieve the results of the query. Or it you only want one result: `item = obj[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing there is a [`Cursor`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects) object. It in itself is iterable, and it returns a tuple of the selected values; in your case, a tuple of size 1, with the value being the sequence.

Something like this will work -

```
for values in obj:
    print(values[0])
```

If you queried for something else, so for example, if your query was `select gene_name, sequence from genes where key=54321`, then `values` in the above example will have two items.

If you are absolutely certain that only one result will be returned (or only want the first result), then you can use the [`fetchone`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) method, and avoid the loop altogether.

Comment: Worth mentioning that (1) `obj is cur` and, as a corollary, (2) you can only fetch data up until the cursor has been closed.